# Topology Second edition by James Munkres p85 Example 4.

Tags: general-topology

The set $X=\{1,2\}\times \mathbb{Z}_+$ in the dictionary order is another example of an ordered set with a smallest element.  Denoting $1\times n$ by $a_n$ and $2\times n$ by $b_n$, we can represent $X$ by $$a_1, a_2, ...; b_1, b_2,...$$ The order topology on $X$ is not the discrete topology.  Most one-point sets are open, but there is an exception $-$ the one-point set $\{b_1\}$.  Any open set containing $b_1$ must contain a basis element about $b_1$ (by definition), and any basis element containing $b_1$ contains points of the $a_i$ sequence.

Page 84 of the text states intervals of the form $[a_0,b)$, where $a_0$ is the smallest element of $X$ and intervals of the form $(a,b_0]$ where $b_0$ is the largest element of $X$ are in the basis.  Thus, the basis element $(1,2]\times [1,2)$ would be a basis element for $X$ that contains $b_1$ and does not contain any points of the sequence $a_i$.  What am I missing?

Comment: $(1,2]$ and $[1,2)$ are not intervals of $X$ because $1$ and $2$ are not members of $X$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet isn't $(1,2]$ in the basis for $\{1,2\}$ and $[1,2)$ in the basis for $\mathbb{Z}_+$ so $(1,2] \times [1,2)$ is in the basis for $X$?

Comment: The members of $X$ are ordered pairs of the form $<i,n>$ with $i\in \{1,2\}$ and $n\in\Bbb N.$ The end-points of a non-empty interval in $X$ are members of $X$. But $1$ and $2$ are NOT members of $X$.